# "Asegúrate de que no ..." + subjuntivo/indicativo?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Me pregunto cuál de dos formas es correcta y por qué:

1) "Asegúrate de que él no **está** en contra"

2) "Asegúrate de que él no **esté** en contra"

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Lo mismo las dos son válidas, en la gran mayoría de contextos, y solo una es válida en un contexto dado? Prueba a añadir algo más sobre el contexto o porqué dudas entre los tiempos verbales. Visita [ask] para ver otras preguntas y aprender un poco cómo hacer preguntas más específicas que ayuden a la gente a entender lo que  estás buscando aprender. Además, has visto si hay preguntas existentes sobre subjuntivo que responda ya a tu duda? Y bienvenido a [Spanish.se]

Answer (score 1):

Ambas son correctas. Su significado es ligeramente distinto.

En el primer caso,

> Asegúrate de que él no **está** en contra

El verbo está en indicativo. Se utiliza para hechos y afirmaciones.

Al usar esto, estoy afirmando que él puede estar en contra ya. Solo falta asegurarse, preguntarle, pero la decisión ya está tomada. Él puede estar a favor o en contra, pero ya lo ha decidido. Él "ya lo sabe".

Por eso, usamos el indicativo: `pregunta si eso es verdad`. Puede ser verdad, o puede no ser verdad, pero ya es un hecho: O es verdad, o no es verdad. No hay posibilidad de cambiar nada.

En el segundo caso,

> Asegúrate de que él no **esté** en contra

Al usar el subjuntivo, todavía no es un hecho. Por tanto, la decisión aún no está tomada. Que él esté en contra es una posibilidad, pero que todavía no ha ocurrido.

Yo utilizaría esta opción cuando "él" todavía no sabe qué ha pasado. Tiene una especie de "valor de futuro".

De hecho, puedes decir "asegúrate de que no **esté** en contra antes de contarle **todo**".

Así que el subjuntivo está indicando **posibilidad en el futuro**, mientras que el primero es **certeza en el futuro**.